# Use Foundation instead of Bootstrap with SASS in a yeoman created application

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, yeoman, bower

I've created an AngularJS application with yeoman. Now I want to switch the front-end framework from bootstrap to foundation.

After I installed foundation with `bower install foundation --save`

Grunt will add the following line to my `index.html` file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css" />
```

How can I force grunt to use the sass way.

For the sass way the index.html is untouched (except js files) but the `main.scss` file nedds the following line or simliar

```
@import "../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation"
```

to work with the sass.

Here is the Grundfile.js trigger for `bower.json`

```
watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
  },
}
```

And here is the wiredep task and the compass task

```
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
wiredep: {
  options: {
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
  },
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /..\//
  },
  sass: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
  }
},

// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: './bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
  },
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is the relevant part, so I attached my full [Grundfile.js](https://gist.github.com/createproblem/3ca193394bd28b04ce3e).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've done, there might be more to it and hopefully someone else can find out, but it's working as expected so far.  Hope this helps:

First you want to exclude foundation.css from the wiredep section of gruntfile.js.  Do this by adding `exclude: ['foundation.css'],` to the wiredep section:  (this will remove the call to foundation.css in head of index.html"

```
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
wiredep: {
 ...//
 app: {
   src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
   exclude: ['foundation.css'],
   ignorePath:  /..\//
 },
 ...//
},
```

Then, in the compass section of gruntfile.js, change the importPath to access the scss files located in bower_components/foundation/scss:

```
compass: {
   options: {
   ...//
     importPath: './bower_components/foundation/scss',
   //...
   }
}
```

Lastly, in app/styles, add the common scss files for foundation.

Following Yeoman Angular's naming convention, `main.scss` could look like this:

```
@import 
    "normalize",  // import from bower_components/foundation
    "settings",   // your custom _settings.scss file in app/styles directory
    "foundation"; // import from bower_components/foundation
```

Pardon any unclear or missing steps as I wrote this rather quickly. 
I also have steps to use libsass using grunt-sass, but I removed them figuring that it's out of scope for this question.

Comment: Compass is not processing foundation's saas files inside of `bower_components/foundation/saas/`

Comment: Foundation (I'm using version 5.3.3) seems not to work well with new Compass 1.0.1 and Ruby Sass 3.4. Remove Sass and Compass (`gem uninstall sass ; gem uninstall compass`) and install older version of Compass (`gem install compass --version 0.12.7`); it will use proper version of Sass. And now it works!

Comment: Thanks for this - worked brilliantly for me. Had to make sure I was using Foundation 5.4.3 in bower.json (not the default bower-foundation 4.0.0). I also excluded the settings include for now, but otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: @naneer, do you have a link to your libsass steps, or can you share them, as this is what we would like to do. So far been following the steps outlined in the following, although some parts needed adjusting: http://ravelantunes.com/blog/angular-generator-libsass/