# Foundation 5 with Stylus in a Yeoman AngularJS generator project

Tags: zurb-foundation, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

Is there a Yeoman generator for AngularJS, Stylus and Foundation 5?
How can I integrate foundation into a Standard angular-generator created project and replace scss with stylus? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tried it by my own but there are yeoman generators for Foundation5

https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-zf5
https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-foundation-five

The angular generator is also available

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

For stylus no idea but in the end it's just a special grunt task for processing the CSS files like this one: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-stylus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424898/use-foundation-instead-of-bootstrap-with-sass-in-a-yeoman-created-application